# How to detect specific Flutter BiometricType (touch or face ID) using local_auth 2.0.0

Tags: flutter, authentication

I'm implementing fingerprint and face recognition in my flutter app using local_auth 2.0.0. When calling getBiometrics() the docs list the following as available types:

```
/// Various types of biometric authentication.
/// Some platforms report specific biometric types, while others report only
/// classifications like strong and weak.
enum BiometricType {
  /// Face authentication.
  face,

  /// Fingerprint authentication.
  fingerprint,

  /// Iris authentication.
  iris,

  /// Any biometric (e.g. fingerprint, iris, or face) on the device that the
  /// platform API considers to be strong. For example, on Android this
  /// corresponds to Class 3.
  strong,

  /// Any biometric (e.g. fingerprint, iris, or face) on the device that the
  /// platform API considers to be weak. For example, on Android this
  /// corresponds to Class 2.
  weak,
}
```

My device (Android, Moto G7) only returns `BiometricType.weak` and `BiometricType.strong` - even though it supports fingerprint.

I want to check which types are available, and offer the user to login via either face or fingerprint ID. How can I be sure which is supported by the device in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `local_auth` version 2.0.0, `getAvailableBiometrics` only returns `weak` and `strong` biometric types for Android platform.
Now `getAvailableBiometrics` on Android platform returns only **enrolled** biometric types available on device.

Read more about measuring biometric unlock security: https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure

Comment: But even though it is enrolled, but only shows weak and strong

Answer (score 0):

I was used lower version of local auth(local_auth: ^1.1.11). It's working fine. If greater than 2.0.0. it not worked.