# biometric authentication with flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement face authentication and fingerprint authentication in my application, I want to check if the device has face authentication supported, if true I want to complete with face authentication, if not I want to use fingerprint instead , I tried to use this to determine the types of biometrics the device supports , it gave me a list of two values : BiometricType.weak and BiometricType.strong , here is the code that i have written :

```
    Future<void> checkBiometrics() async {
  bool hasFaceRecognition = false;
  bool hasFingerprintAuthentication = false;

  try {
    List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics =
        await _localAuthentication.getAvailableBiometrics();

    hasFaceRecognition =
        availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.face);
    hasFingerprintAuthentication =
        availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.fingerprint);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }

  if (hasFaceRecognition && hasFingerprintAuthentication) {
    print('This device supports both face recognition and fingerprint authentication');
  } else if (hasFaceRecognition) {
    print('This device supports face recognition');
  } else if (hasFingerprintAuthentication) {
    print('This device supports fingerprint authentication');
  } else {
    print('This device does not support biometric authentication');
  }
}
```

the result is the last condition which is the device does not support biometric authentication, and even though I managed to authenticate using my fingerprint , I still want a way to know the exact biometric methods available

Comment: I asked a similar question. Did you find a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72111458/how-to-detect-specific-flutter-biometrictype-touch-or-face-id-using-local-auth